# Detecting buffering error (or timeout) Android MediaPlayer - Use a Timer for timeout?

Tags: android, timer, android-mediaplayer

Apparently no exception is thrown so that I can recognize an error while buffering streaming audio content.  For example I've disconnected my router and the app will continue to try to buffer the whole time.  When I reconnect then it completes buffering and continues even after being disconnected for over a minute!

So the problem is I can't let my user sit there for that long without considering that a problem.  What is the proper method to detect a buffering problem with the Android media player?

I'm thinking about using a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) for a timeout.  I'll start probably with 15 seconds (using a proxy I tested a 5kbps connection, which would be a worst case, was able to start playing in 6-10 seconds, so I think 15 seconds would be a reasonable timeout period).  Does this sound like a good plan?  If so should I create a new Timer with each buffer attempt or should I keep the same Timer throughout the lifetime of the playback service?

So basically I'm asking two questions:

1) What's the proper way to detect if a buffer is having a problem?  Is there a listener I'm overlooking?  I've tried MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener of course that doesn't fire in my tests.  My conclusion is I have to have a timeout to detect a buffering error.

2) If I'm correct on number one, what is the proper way to use a Timer?  Create one with each buffer attempt or reuse the same one?  **EDIT** Also should I restart the (or cancel and create a new) Timer onBufferUpdate?  With the onBufferUpdate listener I should know that some data is coming back so should maybe reset the timer with that.

Answer (score 4):

From your question, I understand that the primary objective is to detect a situation if your player is stalled due to buffering and take some actions thereof. To handle this situation, I feel that the following 2 listeners may be helpful to identify the same.

[`MediaPlayer.onBufferingUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html) would provide the timely progress of the buffering. So, if there are 2 callbacks with same `percent` value, this could be an indication of potential buffering.

There is another listener [`MediaPlayer.onInfoListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener.html) which has some specific events which could be of interest to you. On this listener, if the `what` is [`MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START), this would indicate that the player is pausing the playback for buffering i.e. trigger for your logic. Similarly [`MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END) indicates the restart of the playback after filling the buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You Should see this article. The mediaplayer has a ErrorListener to get any error.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html

Comment: I'll check that now, the issue is OnError NEVER fired even if it just sat there for a minute.

Comment: That's not an article, that's the documentation and of course I've read that! This is NOT an RTFM situation!  LOL :-)

Comment: For me happens exactly the same than Anthony, the time out take long for call to the error listener. I don't know how fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=40;//for 40 seconds to wait for buffering after it will finish the activity
//boolean timeoutflag=false;

timeout = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                System.out.println("value of count="+msg.getData().getLong("count"));
                if (msg.getData().getBoolean("valid")) {
                    if (msg.getData().getLong("count") == 0 && !timeoutflag) 
                    {

                        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) 
                                {   
                                try
                                {
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                }catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Unable To Load This Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();

                    } else {
                    }

                }

            }
        };
        timeout.postDelayed(null, 0);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (count > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1020);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    Message msg = new Message();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putBoolean("valid", true);
                    b.putLong("count", --count);
                    msg.setData(b);
                    timeout.sendMessage(msg);

                }

            }
        }).start();
        // set timeoutflag=true; in setOnPreparedListener of video view
```

Answer (score 0):

For buffering during preparation, you have to set your own timer which calls player.reset() after some interval. This puts the player back into init state.

For buffering after preparation (during play) you have to monitor getPosition(). If it falls behind some maximum, call reset(). This allows you to set an experience threshold for your playback. Handles not only failed connection, but also choppy connection.

Best solution is to not use MediaPlayer. Use a public VLC derivative instead. MP has too many internalized private design limitations requiring horrible workarounds (eg. CANT add codecs). RTFM gives you false hope in this case.

Unless you are doing a very straight laced android app, don't depend on any android api. Some opensource substitutes are better supported, and for good reason.

(really bandeely olly jolly satisfying editorial rant deleted)